# How to ensure proper drainage in a back yard

Tags: patio

Most homes in the Phoenix Metro area have slump block walls around separating the side and back yards. My house has a small side yard with a grass area and the back area is red brick on half and a pool on the other half. When it rains, it seems like the brick area floods and there is no place for the water to go and I think it's because the grass area is higher than the brick area. Should I be worried? At least it's bricks and the water drains eventually but during "the big one" it could end up flooding the back patio area and 3 inches later it's in the house.

Comment: some pictures will help a lot...

Answer (score 3):

See  [How to build a french drain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/how-to-build-a-french-drain)

This is exactly the purpose for one. They are made to drain water from areas that have poor drainage from clay in the soil or other problems,
I would put it in right on the edge of the grass and the brick. That way the water from the grass will flow into it before reaching the brick and the water from the brick will flow into the drain before it ever reaches your house.

Comment: Never heard of a "french drain". I'll check that out.

Comment: and? what it will be? i voted for the french drain...